# Remove all sub-elements of an item in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.5

I have a QTreeView with an element baseItem which itself contains some children:

```
baseItem
  - child1
  - child2
  - child3
```

Now I want to delete all children of this item but not the item itself. My current approach is to call

```
if (baseItem->hasChildren())
    baseItem->removeRows(rowCnt,baseItem->rowCount());
```

...where rowCnt is the row index number where baseItem is located at. Unfortunately this does work only when baseItem is at rowCnt=0. What could be wrong here? How else should I delete all children of baseItem?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all rows and child rows from QTreeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056529/how-to-remove-all-rows-and-child-rows-from-qtreeview)

Comment: Alexis P.: no, this thread describes how to clear the complete tree, what I want to do is remove only children of a specific element in the tree while this element and all the other ones stay alive

Comment: Does baseItem->parent()->removeRows(baseItem->row(),baseItem->rowCount()); work? cant test it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...where rowCnt is the row index number where baseItem is located at.

No, rowCnt is the index in the subtree under the parent.
So:

```
if (baseItem->hasChildren())
    baseItem->removeRows(0,baseItem->rowCount());
```